# Refresh all referenced fields in an Excel sheet using Macro(VB code)

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that references most of its values from another Excel tab on the same spreadsheet i.e. `=Data!D11` for example updates the field value with the value it is referencing from.

I have previously written the following VB MACRO code which gives a popup box to input a row number to update which contains hard coded fields for the rows selected, but what if I wanted to update all fields, as in being able to choose what columns and rows that needs to be updated?, I basically need a Macro VB code that will allow me to update all fields that are being referenced on the page if requested by the user.

I'm a bit confused to why Excel doesnt update them itself, but this automation should help update all referenced fields within the spreadsheet simply by running the Macro, unless there is another way to actually "refresh" the fields to display the new values?

```
Sub UpdateFormulas()

    Dim LRowNumber As Long

    LRowNumber = InputBox("Please enter the row number to update the formulas.")

    Sheets("Form").Select

    'All following code will copy a formula into the destination if the source
    'has a value.  If the source does not have a value, it will copy a blank to
    'the destination.

    'Item #1
    Range("F7").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("Data!A" & LRowNumber).Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Data!A" & LRowNumber
    End If

    'Item #2
    Range("F9").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("Data!B" & LRowNumber).Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Data!B" & LRowNumber
    End If

    'Item #3
    Range("J10").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("Data!C" & LRowNumber).Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Data!C" & LRowNumber
    End If

    'Item #4
    Range("H11").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("Data!D" & LRowNumber).Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Data!D" & LRowNumber
    End If

    'Item #5
    Range("D11").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("Data!E" & LRowNumber).Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Data!E" & LRowNumber
    End If

    'Reposition back on item #1
    Range("F7").Select

    MsgBox ("The formulas were successfully updated to row " & LRowNumber & ".")

End Sub
```

Or should I just a Pivot table be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in a loop.

```
Sub UpdateFormulas()

Dim LRowNumber As Long
Dim FRowNumber as Long
Dim r as Long

FRowNumber = InputBox("Please enter the first row number to update the formulas.")
LRowNumber = InputBox("Please enter the last row number to update the formulas.")

Sheets("Form").Select

For r = FRowNumber to LRowNumber

         'Item #1
        With Range("F7")
        If IsEmpty(Range("Data!A" & r).Value) Then
           .Value = ""
        Else
            .Formula = "=Data!A" & r
        End If
        End With

        'Item #2
        With Range("F9")
        If IsEmpty(Range("Data!B" & r).Value) Then
            .Value = ""
        Else
            .Formula = "=Data!B" & r
        End If
        End With

        'Item #3
        With Range("J10")
        If IsEmpty(Range("Data!C" & r).Value) Then
            .Value = ""
        Else
            .Formula = "=Data!C" & r
        End If
        End With

        'Item #4
        With Range("H11")
        If IsEmpty(Range("Data!D" & r).Value) Then
            .Value = ""
        Else
            .Formula = "=Data!D" & r
        End If
        End With

        'Item #5
        With Range("D11")
        If IsEmpty(Range("Data!E" & r).Value) Then
            .Value = ""
        Else
            .Formula = "=Data!E" & r
        End If
        End With

Next

    MsgBox ("The formulas were successfully updated to rows " & _
        FRowNumber & " to " & LRowNumber & ".")


End Sub
```

If you do not want to rely on input boxes, you can dynamically set the `FRowNumber` and `LRowNumber` variables. Something like:

```
FRowNumber = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row
LRowNumber = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Thanks David, although Im getting a "Next without For" compile error, it doesnt seem like that though...

Comment: try again... I forgot the last `End With` statement. I think that would trigger the error you describe. Also made another revision in Item #5 (forgot to change `LRowNumber` to `r`).  Let me know if it still causes any trouble.

Comment: Awesome its working, Its funny how a VBA compile error can say one thing, but mean something totally different.

Would it be possible to remove the ranges and just update the Selected rows and columns that have referenced values?, as it seems that the fields that are in ranges are turning empty but the others that aren't specified are being updated.

Comment: well the error was happening because compiler was encountering an `End If` inside the with block (which I had not closed by `End With`), so the error message was actually correct -- just a little ambiguous, as they often are.

Comment: In your example code you only update 5 cells, and these cell ranges are hardcoded. So, in this `For...Next` loop, they are being updated 5 times, each time overwriting the previous update. This is probably not what you want.  Perhaps revise your original question to better describe the desired output, because as-is, there is no way for me to know what you expect to happen.

Comment: Good point, I have updated my question, please let me know if it doesn't make sense, Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Hi David, I think this is what I should have done in the first place?: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-HP010102348.aspx#BMnoaskauto